# User class inherits IdentityUser; how to handle the need for multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a User class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    //other stuff....
}
```

Now I have other classes representing people like `Customer`, `Employee`, `SecurityGuard`... etc.

I want them all to inherit the `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UID { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

Composition would be a godsend at this point, but since EF Core doesn't yet support complex types, I'm stuck. Are there any ways around this?

Comment: Why don't you either put the properties into `User` or make `Person` inherit from `User`?

Comment: Because other classes need to inherit from Person and they're not users in the app (Customer, Employee etc.).
Putting the properties into User would mean copying the code into every other class... which is my only option at this point.

Comment: Extract the properties of `Person` to interface `IPerson`. Let `User` also implement `IPerson`. Yes, it's duplication of code, but since `User` already has a base class, it's the best C# allows while still allowing you to pass `User` to methods that work with person-like attributes.

Answer (score -2):

Not every `User` is a `Person`. Often apps have some "background" users/processes (autocorrect service, scheduled tasks, etc), which still perform actions that should be registered/logged.

So you may create `Person` property in `User` class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    //other stuff....
}
```